# Использование Redis для хранения хеш-сумм свойств товаров. Интеграция с 1С

Tags: php, mysql, оптимизация, 1с, redis

На сайте нужно реализовать интеграцию с 1С. Объем данных большой - 150К товаров.
Выгрузка полная, раз в день. В основном изменяются только цены из-за курса валют и остатки. Могут также и другие данные изменяться.

Для ускорения импорта, чтобы при каждой интеграции не обновлять все товары, а изменить только изменения, было принято решение использовать хеш суммы.

Для каждого товара две хеш суммы, одну для цен и остатков, т.к. часто меняются, вторую для общего списка характеристик.

Хеш суммы мы храним в таблице БД (mysql), в стоге получается 300 тыс записей.
И при каждой интеграции сравниваю с начало хеш суммы, а после обновляю товар и устанавливаю новую хеш сумму или пропускаю.

Вопрос в следующем:
т.к. у нас в таблице хеш сумм 300к записей, и на каждой итерации нужно делать запрос, сравнивать хеш суммы, т.е. выборка хеш суммы довольно-таки ресурсозатратно.

Я слышал про хранилище redis, в котором можно хранить данные в виде `key => value`. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу его задействовать ? И на сколько может быть быстрее из выборки из одной таблицы ? Стоит ли изучать эту систему и переписывать на нее?

Правильно ли понимаю, что redis хранит данные в памяти? Тогда может использовать такую альтернативу:

оставить функционал с таблицей хешей в БД, перед очередной интеграцией, сделать полную выборку из БД, и хранить все хеши в массиве `key => value`, далее сравнивать данные за `O(1)` ?

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие были у вас опыты? Какими способами можно решить, чтобы добиться максимальной производительности?

Comment: т.е. идея в том, чтобы определять изменение в ценах или остатках и прочих характеристиках по хешу? Это не прокатит, так как хеш после изменений может остаться точно таким же. 150к товаров раз в день мне представляется совсем небольшой величиной.  И непонятно, почему у вас в течении для не собираются данные по изменениям?

Comment: @VTT не продемонстрируете пример изменений, при которых sha256 хеш "останется точно таким же"?

Comment: А вообще непонятно зачем здесь хеши, достаточно дату последнего обновления сравнивать

Comment: 150К товаров это много, чтобы просто "в лоб" обновлять товары  На практике  сталкивался с работающими магазинами(на виртуальном хостинге) на cms modX и БУС у которых полное обновление ~15K товаров занимало больше часа. Приходилось также прибегать к расчетам хешей для выделения товаров, подлежащих обновлению. Посмотрите мой [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/965741/327441) на похожий вопрос